# Create-react-app fires up from terminal but not vs-code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

I made a simple `create-react-app my-app` and used `npm start` to fire it up in the browser, it works fine and I get the default react logo and everything. The problem is when I try to fire it up in vscode using `code .` or manually load the files to vs-code I just get a blank page when I open it with "open live-server". Any ideas why that might be?

Edit: 3 errors I'm getting in the console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error. 127.0.0.1:5500/public/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live server is for projects that have static assets.

In a react project you do not need to use live server. `npm start` starts up a webpack development server for you on `port 3000`. This is your live server.

You can change your port to whatever you want by going into your `package.json` and modifying the `start` script.

**Linux and Mac**

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "repository": "your repo",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=5000 react-scripts start" //the port 5000 is the update
  },
  "dependencies": { ... },
  "devDependencies": { ... }
}
```

**Windows**
`"start": "set PORT=5000 react-scripts start"`

Comment: Great, thanks. I used npm start and it opens fine like you say. But what about when I want to edit the project in vscode?

Comment: You mean the source code? `code .` Should open the project up in VS code. If not you can open it directly from VS Code.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work. Or at least I can't edit and save and see results. I think there's probably other issues going on as well with my installation.

Comment: I think the issue is here somewhere ```<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->

Comment: <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>``` here ``` ```

Comment: Typically, you should not have to update your public folder. Your source code lives in the `src` directory

Comment: What browser are you using to open the app?

Comment: Yeah it's weird huh? I'm using chrome

Comment: The comments were there when I loaded the file, I didn't add them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218056/discussion-between-bens-steves-and-marcel-penney).